# ADV7513 on yocto - kernel 4.14

Tags: kernel, yocto, imx6

I am working on IMX6QP with yocto rocko / Linux 4.14.24 and I am trying to use the ADV7513.
My CPU board is a [karo TX6QP](https://www.karo-electronics.de/1262.html).

On my hard :
DISP0_output (IPU1) -> adv7513_in -> hdmi connector

Kernel config:

```
CONFIG_DRM = y
CONFIG_DRM_I2C_ADV7511 = m
```

dtb :
in I2C section :

```
hdmi@39 {
compatible = "adi,adv7513";
reg = <0x39>;
interrupt-parent = <&gpio4>;
interrupts = <11 IRQ_TYPE_LEVEL_LOW>;
pd-gpio = <&gpio3 18 GPIO_ACTIVE_HIGH>;

adi,input-depth = <8>;
adi,input-colorspace = "rgb";
adi,input-clock = "1x";
adi,input-style = <1>;
adi,input-justification = "evenly";

ports {
#address-cells = <1>;
#size-cells = <0>;

port@0 { /* DISP out */
reg = <0>;
adv7513_in: endpoint {
remote-endpoint = <&ipu1_di0_disp0>;
};
};

port@1 { /* HDMI out */
reg = <1>;
adv7513_out: endpoint {
remote-endpoint = <&hdmi_con>;
};
};
};
};
```

In main section:

```
hdmi-out0 {

status = "okay";
compatible = "hdmi-connector";
type = "a";

port {
hdmi_con: endpoint {
remote-endpoint = <&adv7513_out>;
};
};
};
```

The ADV7513 does not up because it is not binded : the function "adv7511_bridge_attach" is never called.

What can I do to bind the encoder on DISP output ?

Any idea ?

rBeal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the binding of ipu1 and adv7511.
Solved with :

```
display: disp0 {
        compatible = "fsl,imx-parallel-display";
        #address-cells = <1>;
        #size-cells = <0>;
        pinctrl-names = "default";
        pinctrl-0 = <&pinctrl_disp0_2>;
        interface-pix-fmt = "rgb24";

        bits-per-pixel = <32>;
        bus-width = <24>;

        status = "okay";

        port@0 {
                reg = <0>;
                lcd_in: endpoint {
                        remote-endpoint = <&ipu1_di0_disp0>;
                };
        };

        port@1 {
                reg = <1>;
                lcd_out: endpoint {
                        remote-endpoint = <&adv7511_in>;
                };
        };
```

The ipu1 is now binded on adv7511.

Solved